# Calendar event generate through php ical is always 1601 year.How can i resolve it?

Tags: php, icalendar

I am creating ical calendar event with php but always from date is set to 1 January 1601.

Here is my code

```
$ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
$ical .= "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
$ical .= "PRODID:-//YourCassavaLtd//EateriesDept//EN\r\n";
$ical .= "METHOD:REQUEST\r\n";
$ical .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
$ical .= "ORGANIZER;SENT-BY=\"MAILTO:support@cajunlodging.com\":MAILTO:support@cajunlodging.com\r\n";
$ical .= "ATTENDEE;CN=".$to_name.";ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:".$to_address."\r\n";
$ical .= "UID:".strtoupper(md5($event_id))."helpdesk.myicloudapps.com\r\n";
$ical .= "SEQUENCE:0 \r\n";
$ical .= "STATUS:CONFIRMED\r\n";
$ical .= "DTSTAMPTZID=Africa/Nairobi:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."\r\n";
$ical .= "DTSTART:".$date_start."\r\n";
$ical .= "DTEND:".$date_end."\r\n";
$ical .= "LOCATION:".$hotel."\r\n";
$ical .= "SUMMARY:".$title."\r\n";
$ical .= "DESCRIPTION:".$detail."\r\n";
$ical .= "BEGIN:VALARM\r\n";
$ical .= "TRIGGER:-PT15M\r\n";
$ical .= "ACTION:DISPLAY\r\n";
$ical .= "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\r\n";
$ical .= "END:VALARM\r\n";
$ical .= "END:VEVENT\r\n";
$ical .= "END:VCALENDAR\r\n";
```

and date format is like Ymd\THis.

So can you guys suggest me where does i am wrong.

Comment: Share the actual output of this script.

Answer (score 2):

The proper date/time format for iCalendar files is `yyyymmddThhmmssZ`.

For example: `20151126T133000Z`

The Z at the end stands for "UTC time".  Dates in this format must be in UTC time.

Answer (score 2):

You say that the date is always set to 1 January 1601.  I assume you mean the DTSTART date.  Now all you have offered for people to help you with this is that you have a variable called $date_start.

1 January 1601 is a 'special' date ([the windows epoch date](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/03/06/9461176.aspx)) which tends to indicate you have not set up your date variable correctly, or whatever is providing the data has not done it right.

Once you have a meaningful date variable, then for your ics file date to be correct, $date_start should be a string in one of the approved ics formats, either for DATE or DATETIME
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.4

Also note you have a syntax error in

"DTSTAMPTZID=Africa/Nairobi...

you need a semi-colon if you going to use TZID
"DTSTAMP;TZID=Africa/Nairobi...